# Get count on a joined tables

Tags: oracle11g

I have two tables(oracle):
(I have marked the primary keys with a star before the column name)

**Table1** Columns are :
    *date,
    *code,
    *symbol,
    price,
    weight

**Table2** columns are :
    *descriptionID
    code
    symbol
    date
    description

I need to find the below information using query,

For a given code and a symbol on a particular day,is there any description.
for example: code = "AA" and symbol = "TEST" on 2012-4-1 on Table 1 => is there atleast one row like ID=, code ="AA", symbol ="TEST" ,date = 2012-4-1 in table 2

I tried with the below query:

```
select * from Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
Table2 t2
on  t1.code = t2.code and t1.symbol = t2.symbol and 
TO_CHAR(t1.date, 'YYYY/MM/DD')  = TO_CHAR(t1.date, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

But it doesnt give me output like:

code = AA, symbol = TEST, date 2012-4-1 => descrition count = 10
code = AA, symbol = TEST, date 2012-4-2 => descrition count = 5
code = BB, symbol = HELO, date 2012-4-1 => descrition count = 20

Can some one suggest me a query which can achieve the above output.

Comment: are you ready for the answer?

Comment: in your query you have `TO_CHAR(t1.date, 'YYYY/MM/DD')  = TO_CHAR(t1.date, 'YYYY/MM/DD')` why convert to string ? shouldn't it be t2 in the right (left) side ? I mean, why not just `t1.date = t2.date`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need the join:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Table2 
WHERE code='AA'
AND symbol = 'TEST'
AND date = to_date('2012-04-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

---

**UPDATE:** (after reading your comment)
I still don't see why you need the join. Do you need some data from table1 ?
Anyway, if you want the count for all the (code,symbol,date)s then why not group by ?
As for the dates, better use `trunc` to get rid of the time parts.
So:

```
SELECT code, symbol, date, count(*)
FROM Table2
GROUP BY code, symbol, date
```

Comment: I need the description count for all the items in table1. not just for code = "AA", symbol = "TEST". That is jst an example. That is why I use join. Using count(*) in the above way just give the count of description for AA-TEST-2012-04-01 only. I can't just use the t1.date = t2.date because t1.date has time parameters and t2.date has only yyyymmdd. I need to compare only date part. I need a single query which will give the description count for each unique code-symbol-date items in table1.

Comment: @user1308004- I updated my answer, as for the dates you can do it like this: `trunc(t1.date) = trunc(t2.date)`

Answer (score 0):

the `Trunc()` Method takes a String\Date input and Creates a DATE output that is in this Format: "DD\MM\YYYY".
So Its should do exactly what you want.